# Simple map function error

Tags: python, python-3.x, built-in

I am trying out the `map` function and it is giving me unexpected output:

```
map(lambda x: x, range(3))
<builtins.map at 0x7fc3f6c0ab70>
```

When I try to call it with `map(lambda x: x, range(3))()`, it says `map` is not callable.

Comment: As of python 3, `map` is no longer considered 'pythonic' (see https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists). The 'correct' implementation would now be a list comprehension; i.e. `[x for x in range(3)]`.

Comment: @PWhite what is the best solution for lazy evaluation? I want to use `yield from` and `yield from (lambda x: for i in range(x): yield i)()` looks ugly

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but `yield from (x for x in range(3))` works in the context of a generator as the `(...)` syntax returns a generator.

Comment: @yayu in Python 3.x, `range` returns a generator, so it already is lazy evaluation, in Python 2.x it used to evaluate the list all at once.

Comment: @Cyber `range` in 3.x is indeed lazy and in for most intents and purposes can be considered one, but is not, strictly, a generator (it's more similar to a lazy list).

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for is

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: x, range(3)))
[0, 1, 2]
```

`map` returns an iterator. The message you are seeing is simply the object type for which you have just created an instance

```
>>> map(lambda x: x, range(3))
<map object at 0x02E11F10>
```

Answer (score 4):

That is not an error.

Instead, it is a representation of the `map` object (an iterator) returned by [`map` in Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> # Python 3.x interpreter
>>> map(lambda x: x, range(3))
<map object at 0x01AAA2F0>
>>> type(map(lambda x: x, range(3)))
<class 'map'>
>>>
```

Note that my output is not exactly the same because I am using a different implementation.  Still, the same principle applies.

[`map` in Python 2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) meanwhile returns a list:

```
>>> # Python 2.x intepreter
>>> map(lambda x: x, range(3))
[0, 1, 2]
>>>
```

But in modern Python, if you want a list result, you need to explicitly convert the `map` object into one:

```
>>> # Python 3.x interpreter
>>> list(map(lambda x: x, range(3)))
[0, 1, 2]
>>>
```

You can read about this as well as similar changes on Python's [What's New in Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html) page.

Comment: oh.. that's why I thought it was strange. And all online tutorials were giving me the old behaviour.

Comment: ok, another question.. I know now that its an iterator so I can use next(), can I use `yield from` with the map object?

Comment: Yes.  Try `def f(): yield from map(str, [1, 2, 3])` for example.